# Stubbing a Presenter model doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, draper

I have a presenter:

```
class MyPresenter < Decorator    
  . . .

  def items
    . . .
  end

  # a method being tested which uses the above method
  def saved_items
    items.reject { |m| m.new_record? }
  end
end
```

and its test:

```
describe MyPresenter do
  . . .

  describe "#saved_items" do
    subject { MyPresenter.new(container) }

    it "doesn't include unsaved items" do
      # I want to stub items method:
      subject.should_receive(:items).and_return([])
      subject.saved_items.should == []
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, this test fails with the following error:

```
  1) MyPresenter#saved_items doesn't include unsaved items
     Failure/Error: subject.saved_items.should == []
       Double received unexpected message :items with (no args)
     # ./app/presenters/my_presenter.rb:35:in `items'
     # ./app/presenters/my_presenter.rb:42:in `saved_items'
     # ./spec/presenters/my_presenter_spec.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why does it fail? Why it calls the `items` method although I have stubbed it?

Comment: I guess I understand, you've a delegate method on items right? and your container is a double?

Comment: Container is a double, yes. Not sure about the delegate method, `items` essentially wrap container's items collection in ItemPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same issue and fixed it this way:

Instead of:

```
subject.should_receive
```

I put:

```
MyPresenter.any_instance.should_receive
```

Comment: Funny, that causes stack overflow in my case. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just not use the `subject` block:

```
 it "doesn't include unsaved items" do
   my_presenter = MyPresenter.new(container)
   my_presenter.should_receive(:items).and_return([])
   my_presenter.saved_items.should == []
 end
```

In case you find duplication in your tests, you could extract out the object instantiation in a `before` block. Often times I find `subject` to be extremely useful, but sometimes simpler tests can result by not using it!